# How to free memory in php class method

Tags: php, mysqli

I present a part of Mine class that works correctly.
But I want your advice in:
How to release resources by `$result->free()` method in function and were to place them in code.

Is it useful to write it at the end of function, when i return value before?
When I have placed it before return operator, function doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

```
require_once 'ggc_config.php';

class ggc
{       

    public static function executequery($querystring, &$id){
        $mysqli = new mysqli(_GGC_HOST_ , _GGC_USER_ , _GGC_PASSWORD_ , _GGC_DB_);
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo("Connect failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
            return 0;
            }//if

        $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
        $result=$mysqli->query($querystring); 
            if ($result===true){
            $id=$mysqli->insert_id;
            return 1;
            }//if
            else{
            return 0;
            }//else
        $result->free();
        $mysqli->close();
    }//executequeryi


    public static function getresults($querystring){
        $mysqli = new mysqli(_GGC_HOST_ , _GGC_USER_ , _GGC_PASSWORD_ , _GGC_DB_);
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            die("Connect failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
            }//if
        $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

            if ($result = $mysqli->query($querystring)){
                while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                    for ($i=0; $i<$mysqli->field_count; $i++){
                        $a[$i][]= $row[$i];
                    }//for
                }//while   
            }//if   
        return $a;
        $result->free();
        $mysqli->close();   
    }//function 

}//End of CLASS
```

due to your advicies I have changet mine code like this:

require_once 'ggc_config.php';

```
class ggc
{       
    public static function executequery($querystring, &$id){
        $mysqli = new mysqli(_GGC_HOST_ , _GGC_USER_ , _GGC_PASSWORD_ , _GGC_DB_);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo("Connect failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
            unset($mysqli);
            return 0;
        }//if

        $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
        $result=$mysqli->query($querystring); 
        if ($result===true){
            $id=$mysqli->insert_id;
            unset($result);
            unset($mysqli);
            return 1;
        }//if
        else{
            unset($result);
            unset($mysqli);
            return 0;
        }//else
    }//executequery


    public static function getresults($querystring){
        $mysqli = new mysqli(_GGC_HOST_ , _GGC_USER_ , _GGC_PASSWORD_ , _GGC_DB_);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            die("Connect failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
        }//if
        $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

        if ($result = $mysqli->query($querystring)){
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                for ($i=0; $i<$mysqli->field_count; $i++){
                    $a[$i][]= $row[$i];
                }//for
            }//while   
        }//if   
        unset($result);
        unset($mysqli);
        return $a;
    }//function 

}//End of CLASS
```

Comment: Honestly, this is a *least* problem with your class

Comment: I can name only a few, like the Georgian comment in the begining. The hardly readable code not following any conventions and your general programming skills (doing operations after the return clause).

Comment: You are right, I'm newbie in php. Please provide me the best tutorial about conventions. But i don't think that my code is hardly readable

Comment: PHP has it's own garbage collector. In most cases, you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: The way you are building your results array is also a very strange one. Let me suggest you to refrain from writing classes for a while and concentrate on a more basic things like arrays.

Comment: I want to return two dimensional array instead of $result;

Comment: It's very original solution. and how you you would write this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Of course, the way you wrote it is somehow wrong. You can not do anything after the return clause because it will end the function execution. You'll need to free the result BEFORE returning.

The way you wrote it, with:

```
$result->free();
$mysqli->close();
```

would work as well as soon as you place the return clause after the that.

```
$result->free();
$mysqli->close();
return $a;
```

Comment: and exactly where to place the unset() function ?

Comment: ... and added new mistakes as well. What is the "scope of the while loop" you are talking about?

Comment: @user3326849 I updated my answer completely noting your mistakes.

Comment: @YourCommonSense The while loop that iterates over the results. `$a` is not defines anywhere outside the curly brackets of the while, causing it's value not to be accessible outside the while loop, after each iteration.

Comment: You're confusing global/local variables in functions.

Comment: thanks Your answer was usefull. You have corrected my first steps. unfortunatly i havn't enough reputation to vote up your question. And please give me the link of best tutorial about then conventions, how to write code normally.

Comment: Itay Grudev, Your Common Sense,  I have updated My question due to your advice. please comment the new code now.

Comment: @user3326849 why you are appealing to me? You did NOTHING of what I told.

Comment: @user3326849 You can still initialise the `$a` variable like `$a = array();` before the if statement for available results, because if no result are available an unknown value will be returned. Instead if initialised it will return an empty array which at least is predictable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'll do it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to free anything at all.

But this is a least problem with your class, you know.

Comment: at least you have to connect only **once** per application and your methods should support prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

put the return **after** free and close connection.

```
    $result->free();
    $mysqli->close();
    return $a;
```

Comment: as I wrote above, this doesn't return value at all

Answer (score -1):

Its correct variant of my function. I have updated variable names as PEAR NAME CONVENTION requires and added $a=array(); statement.

```
 public static function getResults($queryString){
        $mysqli = new mysqli(GGC_HOST , GGC_USER_ , GGC_PASSWORD , GGC_DB);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            die("Connect failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
        }//if
        $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
        $a=array();        
        if ($result = $mysqli->query($queryString)){
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                for ($i=0; $i<$mysqli->field_count; $i++){
                    $a[$i][]= $row[$i];
                }//for
            }//while   
        }//if   
        unset($result);
        unset($mysqli);
        return $a;
    }//function
```